# group by id and get difference of dates in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
  id  Type   Sale     SaleDate  Time    Cat     LoadType      LoadDate
 A11   ABC    123   15/11/2016 00:00    AAA       Unload    23/11/2016
 A11   ABC    123   15/11/2016 00:00    AAA         Load    17/11/2016
A556   ABC    444   09/01/2017 00:00    VVV       Unload    17/01/2017
A556   ABC    444   09/01/2017 00:00    VVV         Load    17/01/2017
```

I want to get the difference between LoadDate for each id. For instance it should return

```
id   ....   LoadDate    DifferenceInDays
A11  ....   23/11/2016      6   
A11  ....   17/11/2016      6
```

The DifferenceInDays should be the same for both rows with the same id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group by `id`, then calculate `max(LoadDate)` - `min(LoadDate)`. Assuming your data frame is named `myData`:

```
library(dplyr)
  myData %>% 
  mutate(SaleDate = as.Date(SaleDate, "%d/%m/%Y"), 
         LoadDate = as.Date(LoadDate, "%d/%m/%Y")) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(DifferenceInDays = max(LoadDate) - min(LoadDate))
```

Result:

```
     id   DifferenceInDays 
  <chr>             <time>
1   A11             6 days
2  A556             0 days
```

Use `mutate()` instead of `summarise()` if you want to add the column to the original data frame.

Comment: I get an NA's in all values for 'diff' in the resulting dataframe

Comment: Code works for me with your example data. Make sure to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you create the data frame.

Comment: Yes. They're all 'chr's . There are no fctrs. Even Sample.Date when mutated gets filled with NAs

Comment: `Sample.Date` ? Your example data had `SaleDate`. Code in the answer works with the example data provided in the question.

Comment: I meant LoadDate, sorry.

Comment: Works fine. Had an issue with my date formatting. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with `data.table`:

```
require('data.table')

# Your example data, in a data.frame
df = read.table(text='id  Type Sale SaleDate  Time    Cat     LoadType  LoadDate
A11 ABC 123 15/11/2016 00:00    AAA     Unload  23/11/2016
A11 ABC 123 15/11/2016 00:00    AAA     Load    17/11/2016
A556    ABC 444 09/01/2017 00:00    VVV     Unload  17/01/2017
A556    ABC 444 09/01/2017 00:00    VVV     Load    17/01/2017', header=T)

# convert to a data.table...
dt = data.table(df, key='id')

# ... with the right format for the date
dt[, LoadDate := as.IDate(LoadDate, format='%d/%m/%Y')]

# computes the difference in days, by ID:
dt[, DifferenceInDays := diff(range(LoadDate)), by=id]
```

This gives the desired output:

```
> dt
     id Type Sale   SaleDate  Time Cat LoadType   LoadDate DifferenceInDays
1:  A11  ABC  123 15/11/2016 00:00 AAA   Unload 2016-11-23                6
2:  A11  ABC  123 15/11/2016 00:00 AAA     Load 2016-11-17                6
3: A556  ABC  444 09/01/2017 00:00 VVV   Unload 2017-01-17                0
4: A556  ABC  444 09/01/2017 00:00 VVV     Load 2017-01-17                0
```